# Meaning of "sitting by the hour"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Mrs. Pritchard was to accompany me on the train that would take me on
> the overnight trip from Nairobi to Mombasa, where I would board the ship.
> For three days I had resisted wearing Valerie’s clothes, but now I had to put
> them on. Mrs. Pritchard herself had altered the clothes to fit me, **sitting by the
> hour**, tears dropping onto the silks and linens as she took in seams and
> shortened hems. Seeing her unhappiness, my dislike began to melt away.

I checked the meaning of "by the hour" on the net as **every hour**, but in this context I think its meaning is something different.

Does it mean:

1. She sat fitting the clothes for an hour?

or

2. She sat fitting the clothes for hours?

Source: *Listening for Lions* by
Gloria Whelan

Answer (score 1):

The correct meaning is option 2.

[Look it up](https://shorturl.at/hwyY1) and you will see from context the persons are sitting hour after hour

> Sunday was his only day off, and I recall his sitting by the hour at a desk in the living room decorating stamp album pages with carefully rendered designs.

---

> Our debates continued endlessly. On long walks or sitting by the hour over cups of coffee, he would enthusiastically attempt to “prove” that true music was born with Wagner

---

> by the hour​/​from hour to hour continuously, or all the time
> The fire grew bigger by the hour.

<sup>[macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/by-the-hour)</sup>